# Want to map a part of my video on a plane same place as in the shot

Tags: shader-nodes, vector-mapping

I'm trying to map the mirror that is in my video shot on this plane same place as in the shot to make an matrix effect but I can't make fit.

A video screen of my problem : https://youtu.be/EqXlpnCOR_M

[image]